# Here Map JS cluster marker remove option

Tags: here-api

On map using cluster layer to display the marker , on API call loading  the data on reload i need to clear clustered marker in the map please help on this issue,normal marker to clear using current method (map.removeObjects(map.getObjects()) it working as excepted but i need remove default  cluster marker

Please find the below code :

```
 startClustering(map, data) {
    // First we need to create an array of DataPoint objects,
    // for the ClusterProvider
    // tslint:disable-next-line:ter-prefer-arrow-callback
    const dataPoints = data.map(function (item) {
      console.log('item>>>>', item);
      return new H.clustering.DataPoint(item.y, item.x);
    });

    const clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
      clusteringOptions: {
        // Maximum radius of the neighbourhood
        eps: 1,
        // minimum weight of points required to form a cluster
        minWeight: 2,
      },
    });

    // Create a layer tha will consume objects from our clustering provider
    const clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
    // To make objects from clustering provder visible,
    // we need to add our layer to the map
    map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);

  }
```

i need to remove this cluster marker before call this funcation

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach will be to keep a reference to the cluster layer you wish to remove and then remove it by:

Given a reference called `clusteringLayer`:

> map.removeLayer(clusteringLayer);

The other alternative of using `map.getLayers()` to retrieve all map layers and removing each layer via `map.removerLayer(<layerRef>)` might remove layers you do not wish to remove.